# Typescript data type of array of un-instantiated class

Tags: typescript

I would like to implement 'trait' (as in PHP) feature into Typescript class. I thought that this the code below would work, but it doesn't. I don't know why as it makes sense to me.

```
interface Trait {
    register: (Model: BaseModel, option?: object) => void
}

interface IPrototype {
    prototype: any;
}

class Tenable implements Trait {
    register(Entity: BaseModel & IPrototype, option = {}) {
        Entity.prototype.hello = function () {
            console.log('Hello World from Tenable!');
        }
    }
}

class BaseModel { 
  protected traits: Trait[] = [];
}

class A extends BaseModel {
  protected traits = [Tenable];
}
```

If you run this code in Typescript Playgound, you can see the error. [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Trait%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20register%3A%20(Model%3A%20BaseModel%2C%20option%3F%3A%20object)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IPrototype%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prototype%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Tenable%20implements%20Trait%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20register(Entity%3A%20BaseModel%20%26%20IPrototype%2C%20option%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Entity.prototype.hello%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Hello%20World%20from%20Tenable!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BaseModel%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20protected%20traits%3A%20Trait%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20BaseModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20protected%20traits%20%3D%20%5BTenable%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means an array of `Trait` objects.

```
protected traits: Trait[] = [];
```

But here you create an array with a `Trait` object **constructor**.

```
protected traits = [Tenable];
```

To have a list of constructors that construct such an object, you need to change your traits type.

```
protected traits: (new () => Trait)[] = [];
```

Comment: Oh I see. How do I declare the type of `traits` where it just accepts the class without initializing it? I want to have a method in BaseModel that instantiates it and applies them.

Comment: Oh I see. I don't know where it stated in this Typescript doc, but you got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of `Trait`s (the class)

You can change `Trait` from an interface to an abstract class

```
abstract class Trait {
  register: (Model: BaseModel, option?: object) => void;
}
```

and then use `typeof`

```
class BaseModel {
  protected traits: Array<typeof Trait> = [];
}
```